# Are the irreducible components of a codimension one subvariety also codimension one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Assume the field $\mathbb{K}$ we're working over is algebraically closed. Let $V$ be an irreducible affine variety and let $Z\subset V$ be a closed subvariety of codimension $1$. Is it true that all the irreducible components of $Z$ are also of codimension $1$?

I know this is true if $Z=\mathcal{V}(f)$, i.e., it is a vanishing set of some $f\in\mathbb{K}[V]$. (it follows from Krull's zero ideal theorem)

[I'm asking the above question because of this fact]

Comment: Well, you can embed the disjoint union of a line and a point into the plane, and the plane is irreducible.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why does this example fail in the case of $Z=\mathcal{V}(f)$?

Comment: Can you write the disjoint union of a line and a point as the zero set of a single polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Are the irreducible components of a codimension one subvariety also codimension one?"

**Answer:** If $A:=k[x,y,z]$ and $I:=(x),J:=(y,z)$, it follows the ideal $IJ$ define a codimension one subscheme $X:=V(IJ)⊆\mathbb{A}^3$ (the dimension of the component of largest dimension is one). $X$ has two irreducible components: One of dimension $2$ and one of dimension $1$. Hence the answer is "no".